# fakefs and real files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

How do you copy a directory from the real filesystem to fakefs during a rspec test?

Is there an easier way to do this than to reconstruct the directory structure, load the files to memory before enabling fakefs, enabling fakefs, and then outputting the files to fakefs?

Answer (score 1):

[FakeFS::FileSystem#clone](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/defunkt/fakefs/FakeFS/FileSystem#clone-instance_method) will do exactly what you need.